# Why is Plain-Vanilla Bond most common bond in the market?

Tags: fixed-income, bond

I have very straigtforward question (in my perception):

Is there any study/research/evidence that provides insights on the following question(s):
Why is plain-vanilla most common bond in the market? Why it has highly level lequidity, why issuers and investors more prefer to trade with plain-vanilla, than with other varieties of bonds?

Comment: why is money typically denominated in 5s 10s 20s 50s 100s, as opposed to 11s 23s 66s and 189s?

Comment: @Attack68 I don't think that your comment has any relationship with my question.

Answer (score 1):

I'll hazard an answer: because people/investors like to receive interim payments when lending money, hence coupon bonds are more common than zero coupons, and for issuers it means less credit risk premium to pay. People/investors also like dividend paying stocks. Gives them a (false) sense of security. But investor psychology is not my expertise, so my guess is as good as yours.

This is not a quantitative finance question though, nor is mine a quantitative finance answer.